# Object reference undefined in code, but not in console

Tags: javascript

when I put this in my `app.js`:

```
var titres = document.querySelectorAll('header ul li a')

console.log(titres)
```

It send me back this: `[]`

if I put this in the console on the browser :

```
var titres = document.querySelectorAll('header ul li a')
```

`titres` send me back this: `[a,a,a,a,a]`

Someone knows why please ?

Comment: Post a [mcve] please. We need your HTML

Comment: Because there are 5 anchor elements on the page

Comment: Put that `.js` file at the bottom of your HTML file, right before `</body>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you type those statements into the console, the page has already been fully parsed, so the elements are found and your are returned an "array-like" object containing references to those elements.

But, most likely, when you try it with the code in `app.js`, your `app.js` file is being executed before the entire HTML page has been parsed into memory, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- At this point, the rest of the HTML hasn't been parsed yet, so
         if app.js tries to query for those elements, they won't be found! -->
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
  </head>
  <body>

  .  .  .
```

Try either putting the `<script src="app.js"></script>` code just before the closing of the `body` element (so that it runs after the HTML is already parsed) like this:

```
    .  .  .
    <script src="app.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

or leave the `script` tag at the top of the page, but inside the `app.js` file, wrap your code in an event handler like this:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var titres = document.querySelectorAll('header ul li a')
    console.log(titres)
});
```

which will defer the execution of the code until after the HTML is loaded.

Comment: Thank you dude, 
My <script> was a to top of the body. So it is the same if I put it in the <header> as well then ?

Comment: @BenoHiT Yes, the browser reads the code sequentially, so if your JavaScript is encountered before the bulk of the HTML, the JavaScript can't find it.